# how to set two Variable with one select in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

i have two Variable type in t-sql and want set they in sql. i use this code:

```
DECLARE @Id int
DECLARE @Name nvarchar(100)
set @Id, @Name = (Select Id, Name From Member Where username = @username)
```

but this not working, and i not want use this code:

```
set @Id = (Select Id From Member Where username = @username)
set @Name = (Select Name From Member Where username = @username)
```

i have use one select.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the right syntax for what you want to do:

```
DECLARE @Id int
DECLARE @Name nvarchar(100)

SELECT @Id = Id, @Name = Name
From Member 
Where username = @username
```